# SQL*Loader loading XML with missing tag

Tags: oracle, tags, sql-loader

I'm analyzing problems with loading XML data through SQL*Loader.

A problem is when the file content is variable:

```
<customer>
  <name>abc</name>
  <surname>abc</surname>
  <address>abc</address>
</customer>
<customer>
  <name>abc</name>
  <address>abc</address>
</customer>
```

If the surname node is not found than the record is not loaded and the log file shows

```
Record 1: Rejected - ...Initial enclosure character not found
```

I would like to use a default value if the tag is not found. "null if"  does not work. How can I do that?

this is my control file:

```
FIELDS (
  dummy1   filler  terminated by "<customer>",  
  name             enclosed by "<name>" and "</name>",  
  surname          enclosed by "<surname>" and "</surname>" NULLIF (surname = "unknown"),
  address          enclosed by "<address>" and "</address>", 
  dummy2   filler  terminated by "</customer>"
)
```

Comment: Can you add your current control file to the question?

Comment: NULLIF does the opposite of what you want - it sets the column value to null if it has a particular value. I don't think you can do this; SQL\*Loader needs to know the positions of each field in the data file, and doesn't expect one to be missing entirely. I'm still not really sure why you're trying to load XML this way when there are better alternatives.

Comment: I also tried with nvl. Not work

Comment: I am analyzing the problems of loading xml with sql loader .
 Later analize the way XMLTable .
there is another way to effect a shred xml in oracle ?

Comment: There's a [section in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e23094/xdb25loa.htm#ADXDB2900). You could also load into a staging table as a single string and then use XMLTable to extract the relational data; not sure if that's what you mean.

Comment: Yes, but I wonder if there are other ways to do it

Comment: This would be ugly but you could you write a program to pre-process the xml file.  Read it line by line writing to an output file.  If you encounter an address tag without a prior surname tag, then write a surname line with your "unknown" value before writing the address line.  Then load the output file.